# Problems saving docx file on nt-server share

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, network-shares, microsoft-office-2007

I'm having troubles saving docx files on a nt-server share. If i save it as 97-2003 format (doc), it works, but not as .docx.
Any clues?

Comment: What happens if you use something like Notepad to create a file in this share with a four character extension, docx or other?

Comment: Which version of Windows NT are you using?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 7 Microsoft changed network storage expectations. Any old NAS or linux Samba share will not do - it has to be the latest and greatest Windows Server or else you have the situation you have here with files taking forever and a day to save.

The network authentication is different too - not that it should be responsible here. Stepping down the network authentication expectations will not help.  What is possibly going on is that your PC writes out updates to the file, not the whole thing on one go during 'autosave' and full save. Your server pretends to be deaf during this process, times out and then your PC does a regular save, or maybe not on your machine!

To solve the problem move to a newer server with Sharepoint etc. Or go the other way and stick to XP.